# Broken symmetry and three-photon vertex

Tags: photons, gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, charge-conjugation

I know that loop-level three-photon vertex in QED is zero since the contribution from fermion and antifermion cancel each other.
Also, from what I know this has something to do with gauge invariance of the QED.

However, my question is "is this true even when the gauge invariance is broken?".
If the gauge invariance is broken, I guess the photon will not only get a mass, but also there will be additional contribution from longitudinal mode of the photon which I am not sure whether this will change the story.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking. Gauge invariance is broken by what? The photon is massless and QED is just $U(1)$ gauge theory...

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I was just thinking about general U(1) gauge boson, not specifically for QED photon. I thought this might be more familiar to think of. U(1) gauge symmetry can be broken by some reason (Dark photon get mass from broken U(1) gauge field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Odd-photon vertices vanish by [Furry's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furry%27s_theorem), a consequence of [Charge conjugation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-symmetry), not gauge invariance. So, adding a photon mass term bilinear, which breaks gauge invariance but preserves C, will still enable Furry's theorem, and exclude effective odd-photon vertices.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!